# Create mysql view from 2 tables with should match on first table column value and second table column value

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Hi,
I have two WordPress tables using which I am trying to generate a new view. Now how to make sure the new view I am generating has a value that matches with first table column value and second table column value.

For example, I want to generate a view where the entry_id of table 1 matches with id of table 2 and
the value of meta_key 4.3 should be equal to '' in table 1 and payment_status='Paid' in table 2

Generate Below view where Meta_value='Ind_City_1_Loc_1' in table 1 and payment payment status = 'paid' in table 2.
[image: Table 3]

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = 'given_transaction_id' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'TransactionID',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '17' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE '1'
    END) AS 'Quantity',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '7.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'First Name',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '7.6' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Last Name',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '8' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Email',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '9' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Contact',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '20.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Member 1',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '27.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Member 2',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '34.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Member 3',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '41.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Member 4',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN p.meta_key = '48.3' THEN p.meta_value
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Member 5'
FROM
    pday_gf_entry_meta AS p,
    pday_gf_entry AS pm
WHERE
    (p.entry_id = pm.id AND p.form_id = '12')
GROUP BY p.entry_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're describing would be qualified as a `VIEW`, constituted by a `JOIN` - rather than a new table altogether.

My `MySQL` skills are a bit dusty, but you could technically `INSERT` based on a condition as you're describing, but you would need to create your destination table first.

In any case, the creation of a `VIEW` is likely the shortest path to your solution.

Also, if you use the **code formatting tools** -- whether it be through the WISYWIG toolbar or Markdown, you may receive better advice/attention.

For example:

````
select MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = 'given_transaction_id' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'TransactionID', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '17' THEN p.meta_value ELSE '1' END) AS 'Quantity', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '7.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'First Name', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '7.6' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Last Name', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '8' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Email', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '9' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Contact', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '20.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Member 1', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '27.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Member 2', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '34.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Member 3', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '41.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Member 4', MAX(CASE WHEN p.meta_key = '48.3' THEN p.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Member 5'

from pday_gf_entry_meta as p, pday_gf_entry as pm

where (p.entry_id = pm.id and p.form_id = '12')

group by p.entry_id```
````

Comment: Thank you, will check it further.

Comment: Yes creating a view helped it quickly. Thank you. My basics are very bad.